# Simple Popup by using Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, popup

I am new to using AngularJS. I have 4 buttons named Cancel, Deny, Success & Remove. If am I click on any button I want to show multiple message i.e. If I click on Cancel then message showing you click on Cancel button & so on.

I have follow from below link but simple alert & no controller is used in this example.

I want a **A MODAL POPUP IN AN ANGULARJS DIRECTIVE** example so I can understand. I have try to google it but no simple examples found.

Please help. Thanks

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="mymodal">


<body>

<div ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="container">
  <button ng-click="toggleModal('Success')" class="btn btn-default">Success</button>
  <button ng-click="toggleModal('Remove')" class="btn btn-default">Remove</button>
  <button ng-click="toggleModal('Deny')" class="btn btn-default">Deny</button>
  <button ng-click="toggleModal('Cancel')" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
  <modal visible="showModal">
      Any additional data / buttons
  </modal>
</div>

        <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"></script>


    <!-- App -->
    <script>
        var mymodal = angular.module('mymodal', []);

mymodal.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.showModal = false;
    $scope.buttonClicked = "";
    $scope.toggleModal = function(btnClicked){
        $scope.buttonClicked = btnClicked;
        $scope.showModal = !$scope.showModal;
    };
  });

mymodal.directive('modal', function () {
    return {
      template: '<div class="modal fade">' + 
          '<div class="modal-dialog">' + 
            '<div class="modal-content">' + 
              '<div class="modal-header">' + 
                '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + 
                '<h4 class="modal-title">{{ buttonClicked }} clicked!!</h4>' + 
              '</div>' + 
              '<div class="modal-body" ng-transclude></div>' + 
            '</div>' + 
          '</div>' + 
        '</div>',
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      replace:true,
      scope:true,
      link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
          scope.$watch(attrs.visible, function(value){
          if(value == true)
            $(element).modal('show');
          else
            $(element).modal('hide');
        });

        $(element).on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
          scope.$apply(function(){
            scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = true;
          });
        });

        $(element).on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
          scope.$apply(function(){
            scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = false;
          });
        });
      }
    };
  });




    </script>
</body>
</html>

Link : http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview
```

Comment: Do you mean Angular Model.?

Comment: I want simple example like an html file which holds html data & other files which holds popup data. And by click of those buttons multiple messages show in popup.

Comment: use this as ref http://jsfiddle.net/alexsuch/RLQhh/

Comment: Thanks @syarul. Html file name I think index.html but what is the name of js file.

Comment: With ngDialog you don't need jQuery or Bootstrap to create dialogs for AngularJS apps - http://likeastore.github.io/ngDialog/#

<----Usage---->
You need only to include ngDialog.js and ngDialog.css (as minimal setup) to your project and then you can start using ngDialog provider in your directives, controllers and services.

Comment: ok I got it. But I don't want to add any external css like bootstrap.

Comment: Thanks @Mike but I want a A MODAL POPUP IN AN ANGULARJS DIRECTIVE.

Comment: you dont have to load bootstrap, remove the class and css link

Comment: In your jsfiddle I have remove bootstrap.min.css & bootstrap.min.js &then it's not working may you pls update that jsfiddle.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Built a modal popup example using syarul's jsFiddle link. Here is the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/92z54z04/1/).

Created an angular directive called modal and used in html.
Explanation:-

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="container">
  <button ng-click="toggleModal('Success')" class="btn btn-default">Success</button>
  <button ng-click="toggleModal('Remove')" class="btn btn-default">Remove</button>
  <button ng-click="toggleModal('Deny')" class="btn btn-default">Deny</button>
  <button ng-click="toggleModal('Cancel')" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
  <modal visible="showModal">
      Any additional data / buttons
  </modal>
</div>
```

On button click toggleModal() function is called with the button message as parameter. This function toggles the visibility of popup. Any tags that you put inside  will show up in the popup as content since ng-transclude is placed on modal-body in the directive template.

JS

```
var mymodal = angular.module('mymodal', []);

mymodal.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.showModal = false;
    $scope.buttonClicked = "";
    $scope.toggleModal = function(btnClicked){
        $scope.buttonClicked = btnClicked;
        $scope.showModal = !$scope.showModal;
    };
  });

mymodal.directive('modal', function () {
    return {
      template: '<div class="modal fade">' + 
          '<div class="modal-dialog">' + 
            '<div class="modal-content">' + 
              '<div class="modal-header">' + 
                '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + 
                '<h4 class="modal-title">{{ buttonClicked }} clicked!!</h4>' + 
              '</div>' + 
              '<div class="modal-body" ng-transclude></div>' + 
            '</div>' + 
          '</div>' + 
        '</div>',
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      replace:true,
      scope:true,
      link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.title = attrs.title;

        scope.$watch(attrs.visible, function(value){
          if(value == true)
            $(element).modal('show');
          else
            $(element).modal('hide');
        });

        $(element).on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
          scope.$apply(function(){
            scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = true;
          });
        });

        $(element).on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
          scope.$apply(function(){
            scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = false;
          });
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

**UPDATE**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="mymodal">


<body>

<div ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="container">
  <button ng-click="toggleModal('Success')" class="btn btn-default">Success</button>
  <button ng-click="toggleModal('Remove')" class="btn btn-default">Remove</button>
  <button ng-click="toggleModal('Deny')" class="btn btn-default">Deny</button>
  <button ng-click="toggleModal('Cancel')" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
  <modal visible="showModal">
      Any additional data / buttons
  </modal>
</div>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>

    <!-- App -->
    <script>
        var mymodal = angular.module('mymodal', []);

mymodal.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.showModal = false;
    $scope.buttonClicked = "";
    $scope.toggleModal = function(btnClicked){
        $scope.buttonClicked = btnClicked;
        $scope.showModal = !$scope.showModal;
    };
  });

mymodal.directive('modal', function () {
    return {
      template: '<div class="modal fade">' + 
          '<div class="modal-dialog">' + 
            '<div class="modal-content">' + 
              '<div class="modal-header">' + 
                '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + 
                '<h4 class="modal-title">{{ buttonClicked }} clicked!!</h4>' + 
              '</div>' + 
              '<div class="modal-body" ng-transclude></div>' + 
            '</div>' + 
          '</div>' + 
        '</div>',
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      replace:true,
      scope:true,
      link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
          scope.$watch(attrs.visible, function(value){
          if(value == true)
            $(element).modal('show');
          else
            $(element).modal('hide');
        });

        $(element).on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
          scope.$apply(function(){
            scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = true;
          });
        });

        $(element).on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
          scope.$apply(function(){
            scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = false;
          });
        });
      }
    };
  });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE 2**
restrict : 'E' : directive to be used as an HTML tag (element). Example in our case is

```
<modal>
```

Other values are 'A' for attribute

```
<div modal>
```

'C' for class (not preferable in our case because modal is already a class in bootstrap.css)

```
<div class="modal">
```

Comment: Its not running, I have add bootstrap.min.js & bootstrap.min.css to above code but its not working.

Comment: are you getting any console errors? You'll need jQuery as well

Comment: No errors, all buttons shows when I click on the button no popup showing.

Comment: Can't say for sure without seeing the actual code. Have u put in ng-app="mymodal". Also, try putting in alert() in toggleModal() & scope.$watch to check if they are being fired on button click.

Comment: You have missed including angular.js and added bootstrap as script instead of link. See my updated post for the corrected code of yours.

Comment: I have just added "<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>" but without click output shows. I think css not call.

Comment: See my update on the post, corrected css as well and now it is working fine

Comment: may you pls tell me what it mean inside mymodal.directive('modal', function (){} i.e. why restrict: 'E' ?

Comment: You need alot more time to actually understand angularjs. 'E' means restricted to element while 'A' for attribute. Which mean a directive pass Atrributes of a DOM and instead look for element.

Comment: Check this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i9MHigUZKEM, start from basic. Directives is quite advance actually

Answer (score 4):

If you are using bootstrap.js then the below code might be useful. This is very simple. Dont have to write anything in js to invoke the pop-up.

Source :http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_modal&stacked=h

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is the simplest way to show Bootstrap 5 modals in Angular JS**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.title = "Bootstrap Modal From HTML & Java Script(Code Behind)"
        $scope.openModal = function () {
            $('#exampleModal').modal('show');
        }
    });
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- JQuery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Angular JS -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <title>Bootstrap Model Eg.</title>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div class="container" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <h2>{{title}}</h2>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal"
                    data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
                    <b>From HTML</b>
                </button>
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success" ng-click="openModal()"><b>From Code-Behind</b></button>
                <!-- Modal -->
                <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
                    aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                                    aria-label="Close"></button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                Model Opened Successfully.. <br>a
                                by <b><i><u>Hritvik Sikarwar</u></i></b> <br>
                                Thank You..
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```